# ListView Similar to google play settings activity in Android

Tags: android, listview, material-design

I want to create a listview like the image bellow:

[image: google play settings activity]

does anyone know how should I make something like that?

Comment: yes you can use the settings activity that android studio provides you when you create a new activity

Comment: Thanks, I tried your solution .  it is actually nice.  but I am wondering how can I make something like that myself.. cause it is nothing like a listview but still functioning like one.. any ideas?

Comment: you dont have to actually make a listview. Just use your imagination. Let me give you an example: You will need a scrollview and a LinearLayout with vertical orientation. For the green section you can use textviews. for the Screenlock patern you will need 2 textviews in their own linear layout and you can then use a click listener and build your own custom dialog to trigger what they do, and then switches. You can use your imagination and make it work

Comment: @helldawg13 I'll try! :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set Peference Fragment. It  contains a hierarchy of preference objects displayed on screen in a list. These preferences will automatically save to SharedPreferences as the user interacts with them.

Define this in xml

```
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<PreferenceCategory
    android:title="@string/title_first_section">

    <CheckBoxPreference
        android:key="checkbox_preference"
        android:title="@string/title_checkbox_preference"
        android:defaultValue="@string/default_checkbox_preference"/>

    <EditTextPreference
        android:key="edittext_preference"
        android:title="@string/title_edittext_preference"
        android:summary="@string/summary_edittext_preference"
        android:dialogTitle="@string/dialog_title_edittext_preference"
        android:dependency="checkbox_preference" />

    </PreferenceCategory>

<PreferenceCategory
    android:title="@string/title_second_section">

    <ListPreference
        android:key="list_preference"
        android:title="@string/title_list_preference"
        android:dialogTitle="@string/dialog_title_list_preference"
        android:entries="@array/entries_list_preference"
        android:entryValues="@array/entryvalues_list_preference" />

    <Preference
        android:title="@string/title_intent_preference">
        <intent android:action="android.intent.action.VIEW"
            android:data="http://codepath.com/" />
    </Preference>

    </PreferenceCategory>
```

You can refer this https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Settings-with-PreferenceFragment